# How to add circleMarkers to different layers in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet, layer

My code generates about 250 Leaflet circleMarkers to show on a map. Each marker belongs to 1 of 3 categories (let's say Red, Green, and Blue markers).
Appreciate a simple example on how to position markers of each category on a separate map layer that can be individually shown/hidden/removed on demand using Javascript or jQuery.

Comment: You can use http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#layergroup

Comment: @xmojmr.. I did it as per your suggestion, and it worked fine (at least with the number of markers I have). I always tried to avoid the layerGroup option as I believe it's too much overhead for the system (supposedly!) to allocate every single marker to a separate layer (with whatever resources it takes for a layer) then have those markers (or layers) grouped in a layer group. But there seems to be no way to create simple layers that can be switched on and off with a number of markers on each.

Comment: @KhalidGomaa a Layer Group is actually quite a simple "layer", the overhead is not very significant. It is designed specifically for use cases like what you describe.